# Align inner tags of Touchable component in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I could not align the inner tags of Touchable component
here is my code:

```
render(){
return(
<View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
<TouchablewithoutFeedback onPress={()=> this.incrementCount()}>
<Text style={{alignslef: 'center'>
Count 
</Text>
</TouchablewithoutFeedback>
);}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the code itself rather than an image of the code. Refer to [ask] for more information.

Comment: already edited it, sorry I am new to StackOverFlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer of my query previously.

```
render(){
return(
<TouchablewithoutFeedback>
<Text style={{**textAlign:'center'**}}>click here</Text>
</TouchablewithoutFeedback>
);
}
```

However, I discovered a complete way to style the button properly because the former answer did not fully recover my styling, the text was aligned to the center horizontally successfully but not vertically.

so here is the complete answer:

```
render(){
return(
<TouchablewithoutFeedback style={styles.btn}>
<Text style={styles.btnText}>
Click me
<Text>
</TouchablewithoutFeedback>
);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
btn:{
width: 200,
height: 200,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center'
},
btnText:{
fontSize: 25,
color: 'red'
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include a style prop for `TouchableWithoutFeedback` that is `alignItems: ‘center’`, or use `textAlign` instead of `alignSelf` inside `Text`’s styles

Comment: What is currently being rendered?

Comment: Great! Nice to hear you fixed it!